# sql to find contract id with members count > 10

Tags: sql

There two tables member and contract.

**member** table

```
(member id, first name, last name, dob)
8880, john,   smith,   1960-01-01
8881, joe,    summer,  1980-01-20
8882, kelvin, clein,   1972-03-11
8883, kelvin, clein,   1982-09-11
9991, stalin, stuwart, 1973-04-12
9992, rosy,   winter,  1985-01-14
```

**contract** table

```
(contract id, member id )
100, 8880
100, 8880
100, 8881
100, 8881
100, 8881
100, 8882
100, 8883

101, 9991
101, 9992
101, 9992
```

I'am looking for a SQL query with a contract id which has members greater than 3.

Comment: With that table data, what's the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *don't* want to count duplicate members associated with a given contract you can try the following query:

```
SELECT contract_id
FROM contract
GROUP BY contract_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT member_id) > 3
```

If you *do* want to count duplicates, then use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(DISTINCT member_id)`.